# Java - are constructors static?

Tags: java, static, constructor

I just wrote a constructor like this:

```
public ArchivesManager(String identifier) {
    String[] components = String.split("\nNEW");
}
```

But there's an error message: `non-static method split(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context`. I know that error message, but why is the constructor static?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because split should be called on a String object. I.e.

```
String foo = "Hello, world";
String[] arr = foo.split(",");
```

Comment: Oh f*ck, yeah, obviously... I had some wrong documentation at hand.

Answer (score 4):

> I know that error message, but why is the constructor static?!

The constructor context is not static, but you explicitly invoked the `split` method in a static context when you qualified it with the classname; i.e. `String.split(...)`.

You probably meant to write this:

```
String[] components = identifier.split("\nNEW");
```

which invokes the method in the (non-static) context of the `String` object passed as `identifier`; i.e. it says *which string should be split*.

Comment: `String[] components = identifier.split("\nNEW");` will it make any sense in constructor ??

Comment: It will if you assume that 1) `identifier` is a constructor parameter (which it is in the OP's example), 2) "\nNEW" is intended to be a regex (which is plausible), and 3) the OP intends to use `component` in the rest of the constructor which he is yet to write or has deleted in an attempt to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the title:

"Constructors are not members" [JLS index] so static isn't really an appropriate concept. Constructors are not members because they are not inherited (I wish static methods weren't inherited either). From a class file point of view, they are special instance methods that return `void`. Bytecode calling the constructor first allocates the memory, duplicates the reference to that memory and then calls the constructor on one of those references. (If targeting 1.4 or later, for an inner class assignment of "outer this" and enclosing `final` fields occurs before calling the constructor.)

Answer (score 2):

because of this `String.split("\nNEW");` `split` isn't static method

you probably need

```
public ArchivesManager(String identifier) {
    String[] components = identifier.split("\nNEW");//NOTE: components are local to const. this doesn't make sense
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `String.split("\nNEW");` you need to call `identifier.split("\nNEW");`. You want to split the identifier object (which is of type string). Essentially what you've said there is "split the string class", which doesn't make sense and hence the compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

This error does not mean that your constructor is static. It means Split is not static method, you have to call this method from its object.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, I don't know why the constructor is static by default. The book "Thinking in Java" says that, "Even though it doesn't explicitly use the static keyword, the constructor is actually a static method."